# FastReport VCL IIF Statement with variables

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am trying to use an if in my report using a variable as the condition this is what I tried `IIF(<Client> = true, "Solde: " + [Solde], "Rendu: " + [Rendu])` but I get the error "undeclared identifier 'Client'"

```
frxReport1.Variables['Rendu'] := Versement - TotalAmount - Remise;
frxReport1.Variables['Solde'] := SoldClient;
frxReport1.Variables['Client'] := ClientTrue; //ClientTrue is a boolean
```

Comment: I see both <> and [] brackets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see these problems:

1. There must be square brackets `[]` all around the expression
2. You should use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` for strings
3. You need to convert your variables values (which I suppose are floating variables) into strings
4. You have to use the angle brackets `<>` only, for using variables in the expressions

Furthermore, you can avoid comparing your  variable (`<Client> = true`), just use the variable since it's a boolean variable.

The following expression will work:

```
[IIF(<Client>, 'Solde: ' + FloatToStr(<Solde>), 'Rendu: ' + FloatToStr(<Rendu>))]
```